# Does anyone know why the title of my legend isn't updating? (ggplot2, stacked barplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

For some reason, I can't get the title of my legend to update from "surv_status" (variable name) to "Survival Status" despite adding +labs(fill = "Survival status") in all different possible places in the code chunk.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
ggplot(data_train, aes(x = axil_nodes, fill = as.factor(surv_status))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
   labs(fill = "Survival status") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Number of positive axillary nodes") +
  ggtitle("Visualizing positive axillary node count by survival status") +   
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", linetype = "dashed")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "surv_status", labels = c("Survived", "Deceased"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different methods you can use to change the title of a legend with `ggplot2`.  I know of three off the top of my head:

- Use `labs(fill= "Legend Title")`, where `fill` can be replaced by whatever aesthetic modifier is associated with the legend.
- Use `scale_*_**()` functions and `name=` argument.  For example, `scale_color_discrete(name="Legend Title")`
- Use `guides()` and declare `title=` within one of the `guide` functions.  For example, `guides(shape=guide_legend(title="Legend Title"))`

If you address the title using more than one method, the priority goes:

1. `guides()` method
2. `scale_*_**()` method
3. `labs()` method
4. Use name associated with mapping - i.e. the name of your column you specify in the `aes()` function.

So the following example shows this clearly.  You can move around each of those references to the `gg` object, but the priority seems to be maintained.  The final legend in the plot with any ordering of the following code will result in the legend being named according to `guides()`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=z)) + geom_point() +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title='My other other legend')) +
  scale_color_discrete(name='My Legend') +
  labs(color='My other Legend')
```

[image]

If I remove the `guides()` part, the legend name is now reflective of `scale_color_discrete()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=z)) + geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name='My Legend') +
  labs(color='My other Legend')
```

[image]

In your example, you have `labs(fill = "Survival status")` as well as `scale_fill_discrete(name = "surv_status"...`.  Using the rules above, you should understand that changing your `labs()` function will never take precedence over `scale_fill_discrete()`.  You can either remove the argument of `name` from `scale_fill_discrete()` or change the value of `name=` within `scale_fill_discrete()` in order to change your legend title.

Comment: Excellent answer (+1). For completeness, you could add a 4th point that the default is taken from the mapping in the first relevant `aes()` function,